# * at end of directory path

Tags: bash, scripting, directory, path

I have a question about the `*` character at the end of a directory path in a bash script.

I have a script that's supposed to automatically delete some archives from a server once they get old enough. The script is on machine A and I need to run it on machine B. I access both machines remotely through `ssh` (no sudo, just regular user). One of the rules of the script is that it needs to only delete archives in the folders beginning with `dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/dirE*`.

However, there is no `dirE` in that location so I'm guessing the `*` stands for some variable. This is what I'd like to know, what does the `*` mean at the end of the directory path and what does it make the script do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `*` here is a "globbing character" and means "match 0 or more characters". To illustrate, consider this directory:

```
$ ls
dirA  dire  dirE  dirEa  dirEEE
$ echo dirE*
dirE dirEa dirEEE
```

As you can see above, the glob `dirE*` matches `dirE`, `dirEa` and `dirEEE` but not `dirA` or `dire` (*nix systems are case sensitive).

So, in your script, that means it will delete archives from any directory in `dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD/` whose name begins with `dirE`.

Comment: hey, not sure if i need to make another thread but i have another question on the same script i thought i'd ask here. so that script that's on machine A has the location of the archives that need to be checked defined as "dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD". However, i need to run the script on machine B with the dirE* condition as well. I suppose i need to edit the script to add this dirE* condition. i

Comment: @kabras yes, please ask a new question. If you need help in editing a script, make sure you include the script in the question. I also suggest you read a simple shell scripting tutorial first to get at least a basic idea of how the language works.

Answer (score 6):

I'll just add a note here for those that come to this Q&A for another reason.

If you see a `*` at the end of a filename in the output of `ls` (actually of `ls -F`, but `ls` is sometimes aliased to `ls -F` (or the `ls-F` builtin in `tcsh`), or of `zsh` or `tcsh` completions, that's something completely different.

With the `-F` option, `ls` adds a trailing character at the end of some *special* file name to help identify their *specialness*. `zsh` and `tcsh` do the same when listing file name completions.

If you see:

```
$ ls -F
dir/  fifo|  file  link@  ls*  socket=
```

Those `/`, `|`, `*` and `=` are not part of the file name (though they might be if someone tried to trick you), but are appended by `ls` to tell you that:

- `dir` is a directory (`/`)
- `fifo` is a named pipe/fifo (`|`)
- `link` is a symbolic link (`@`)
- **`ls` is an executable regular file (`*`)** (has at least one execution bit in its permissions)
- `socket` is a Unix domain socket (`=`)

Some `ls` implementations (and `zsh`'s completion) can also do that differentiation via colours for terminals that support them with different options.